# Tigger hyperlink in one sheet from another sheet

Tags: excel

I have an excel containing 3 sheets. Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3.
Sheet 2 contains around 50 rows. Each of the values in these rows have a hyperlink that on being clicked navigates to a particular cell in Sheet1.
Now, I have all the rows from sheet 2 clubbed inside a dropdown using data validation in Sheet3.
I also have a dynamic hyperlink that grabs the value from the dropdown.
So, suppose,

**Sheet3**

Suppose, there is a dropdown in cell A1 in Sheet3 as shown below containing 3 items. Row1, Row2 and Row3

Row1

Row2

Row3

And there is a hyperlink in cell A2 in sheet3 that grabs the value from the dropdown.
Is there a way I could trigger the hyperlinks that are present inside each row's value in Sheet2 from cell A2 in Sheet3?

Comment: Put the [`hyperlink` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/hyperlink-function-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f) in A2 on Sheet3? If the cells in Sheet2 display the addresses as their text, then simply pass the Sheet2 cell to it as the address, otherwise create a hidden column in Sheet2 with addresses for each cell and pass that to `hyperlink` on Sheet3.

Comment: Thank you so much, Your answer helped me to get in the right direction.

Comment: There reference link was quite helpful.